# How much priming sugar should one use?

Tags: priming

I'm just wondering how much priming solution should one use for a one liter bottle. I'm using dextrose. I don't want my bottles to pop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: 5-10 grams/liter. Lower end will give around 2 volumes, upper end around 3.

Not so simple answer: It is temperature dependent. If your beer has fermented and kept cold, or cold crashed with a lot of co2 in the heads pace then it will contain more dissolved co2 from fermentation and will need less sugar. If it's been warmer at some point it might need more.

I find the simple answer sufficient for anything at ale temperatures (20c +/- 5ish).

Answer (score 1):

150g in 24 litres produces a good carbonation of beer in bottles. So that would be 6g per litre. There is a some margin for error. Adding 5g or 7g to beer in a 1 litre bottle probably will not make the beer flat or the bottle explode.

Answer (score 1):

For my 1 Liter PET bottles, if I'm bottle priming, then I use 2 teaspoons of table sugar or two of the C&H sugar cubes (the larger ones that equal a teaspoon). It's been working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are calculators that can help with this.  There are two variables: Temp and desired carbonation level. Carb level is usually a function of beer style. Here is one [on-line calculator](http://www.northernbrewer.com/priming-sugar-calculator/).

When I started brewing, my kits usually came with 5 oz. of sugar which I used religiously and had plenty of gushers.  Over time I found that approx. 3.9 oz. per 5 gallon batch (115 gram/19 l) works for almost everything. YMMV

Comment: How much is 3.9 oz in the rest of the world ?

Comment: @NeilMeyer 115ml as per https://www.google.com/search?q=3.9oz+in+ml&le=en&btnG=Google+Search&sourceid=Mozilla-search&start=0

Comment: per 5 gallon batch.